# 12 V DC Li battery voltage regulation question

Tags: voltage, motor, voltage-regulator, dc, 12v

I recently bought a 12 V 50 Ah Li battery with the intent to use it for a 12 V DC trolling motor for a boat. The trolling motor runs at up to 30 A. I have read that lithium batteries tend to output higher voltage than the range acceptable for the motor. (Ranges listed at up to a max of slightly over 14 V, for use on a motor that I believe is rated to 13.x) I was wondering if there was a regulator of sorts I could use that would only allow 12 V to 13 V to pass through to the motor. I would need this to be relatively safely done, with no worries about excessive heat or anything, as I would prefer this be inside of a battery box essentially on top of the battery itself.

I don't have the battery yet to do testing to see if I really am getting those voltage levels, but it was a concern other people had when talking about lithium batteries for trolling motors. I am familiar with many low voltage applications, but I struggled to find a product that would do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it like this one? https://relionbattery.com/products/lithium/rb50

Answer (score 1):

Most 12 V motors will not be damaged under normal operating conditions.

At 14 V:

- do not run the motor at no load, it might over speed;
- do not run the motor at continuous full load, it might over heat.

Otherwise it should be fine.

Post the motor specifications and the wiring details for a complete answer.